# java inject local variable in static method

Tags: java, cdi, inject

Is it possible to inject a local variable in java for a static method, like

```
@Inject
public void someMethod()
{
    @MyInjectQualifier MyObjectClass myobject;
    // use myobject here
}
```

Comment: I don't see `static` anywhere...

Comment: You can't. But you could use myObject as a parameter and do setter-injection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot inject a value into a local variable through annotation processing *at runtime*.